# Set sampling clock frequency adjustment for PCM

Tags: alsa

If I am setting the sample rate as 44.1kHz, how does the ALSA driver decide the sampling clock from an embedded hardware? Which source file do I have to refer to for checking frequency adjustments of the MCLK?

I want to write an application for giving the sample clock (ie. MCLK) to my PCM from user space. How can I do that?

Comment: That depends on the hardware. Which you have kept secret.

Answer (score 0):

In ALSA, every device uses its own hardware sample rate clock. So errors between different clocks can accumulate. So far, I have not seen an ALSA driver that allows for clock rate adjustments, neither with a file nor otherwise. But that doesn't mean the ALSA driver for your particular sound card is not the exception, and allows you to do it somehow.

I don't think you can directly access the sample clock from user space (and probably not even from kernel space).

Jack uses a single ALSA device to provide a master clock for everything, which probably means it adjusts buffer sizes according to feedback from ALSA (but this is a guess). I'd look into the Jack code to see how they do this.